# Cambie de proyecto de firestore antes de build la app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, studio, firestore

Queria saber si es posible, cambiar de firestore al que estoy conectado, pasar de firestore 1 a firestore 2, tengo dos proyectos en firestore y quiero que un botón haga el cambio de firestore en flutter, pasa que la conexión a firestore se hace desde antes entonces no tengo posibilidad de elección entre uno u otro.

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Como es el sitio en español, debo pedirte que por favor [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/467132/edit) y traduzcas tu pregunta a español, incluyendo el título.

Comment: Bienvenido revisa [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio y obtengas muy buenas respuestas, saludos.

Comment: Listo perdón publicación editada

Comment: Me suena que lo que pides es imposible. Al menos, todas las preguntas de este tipo que he visto, nunca han tenido una respuesta positiva. Ojalá que alguien más pueda echarte un cable; pero si fuera tú, intentaría tener todo lo que necesites en el mismo FireStore.

Comment: @Manuel gracias, también pensé la misma solución, pero por un tema burocrático, necesito que estas se mantengan separadas, por temas de costos, gracias igualmente